# Make React Native FlatList item on center always active

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Hello! I triyng to complete the functionality displayed on pinned image. I have done this with FlatList's onScroll event, but it change value to slow, active item not always at the middle. Is this some way to always give styles to item, which is on center? Below is my scroll handler.

```
const onScroll = (event) => {
   const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
   const { height: layoutHeight } = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;
   const value = Math.floor(y / itemHeight) + Math.floor(layoutHeight / itemHeight / 2);

   if (activeItem !== value) {
      setActiveItem(value);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add async/await before setting the active item value

```
const onScroll = async (event) => {
   await const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
   await  const { height: layoutHeight } = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;
  await const value = Math.floor(y / itemHeight) + Math.floor(layoutHeight / itemHeight / 2);

 await  if (activeItem !== value) {
      setActiveItem(value);
   }
   }
```